# aligning div containing multiple divs next to a div element

Tags: html, css

I need to align article description to the right of featured image of the article.
I tried using `display:inline` but I seem to be making some mistake.Here is an example of the problem
 http://jsfiddle.net/r8zx9nx5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yous could do this like below CSS, Use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top;` to `.post-description` and `display: inline-block;` to `.entry-image`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8zx9nx5/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
    }
.entry-image img {
    border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.entry-image {
    display: inline-block;
}
.post-description {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.entry-description {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1;
}
.entry-time {
    height: 15px;
    top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.entry-excerpt {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: I need the post-description div to be aligned to the right of image

Comment: isn't the post-description showing to the right of image on my fiddle? JSFiddle Show - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8zx9nx5/1/show/)